# How autowire SessionFactory in Hibernate 5?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin, hibernate-5.x

I try autowire SessionFactory, but get this error:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field bookRepository in com.test.app.BookService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
```

Here I autowire SessionFactory:

```
@Service
class TestClass{
    @Autowired
    lateinit var sessionFactory: SessionFactory
......
}
```

This is my config class:

```
@Configuration
class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    fun sessionFactory(emf: EntityManagerFactory): HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean {
        val fact = HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean()
        fact.entityManagerFactory = emf
        return fact
    }
}
```

I try this way to:

```
@Configuration
class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    fun sessionFactory(): HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean {
        return HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean()
    }
}
```

My application.yml:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: datasource_url
        password: password
        username: username
        hikari:
            maximum-pool-size: 5
    jpa:
        properties:
            hibernate:
                jdbc:
                    batch_size: 20
                current_session_context_class: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

Hibernate version: 5.4.1

Spring boot version: 2.0.0.M3

Comment: Why do you want a `SessionFactory`? Just inject an `EntityManager` to use JPA instead of plain Hibernate. This is basically also what your exception is telling you, it is complaining about an `EntityManagerFactory` NOT a `SessionFactory`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I work with big amount of data and need increase performance. I need Session method saveOrUpdate

Comment: That won't increase your performance. Proper batching techniques will.

Comment: @M.Deinum I try batch, but it is still not enough. So I wanna to try saveOrUpdate

Comment: What did you try? As mentioned saveOrUpdate won't help you trust me. Proper batching techniques (clearing and flushing the entity manager) will.

Comment: @M. Deinum It would be helpful if you post the answer to the relevant question, if you know. Arguing why someone needs it is irrelavant and upto them.